# How to get the parent window URL from Iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, sandbox

I know it's a security issue. But is there any way in HTML5. Cause I seen the below code opens a window with the parents URL in tweet box

```
<iframe src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html"
        style="border: 0; width:130px; height:20px;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this inside the iframe. It will alert the parent window's location URL.

```
alert(document.referrer);
```

Comment: After doing some `url` navigation inside the `iframe`, `document.referrer` value is not returning `parent window URL`, its returning the `current navigation` we have inside the `iframe`. Is there a way to overcome this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Give this JavaScript a go

```
var referrer = document.referrer;
console.log(referrer);
```

Hopefully it works for your purpose. More info on **document.referer** here if you want to know more:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer

Answer (score 2):

One way can be by checking if `window.parent[0].top.document` exists.

If you don't get an error when querying this object assume it's in the same domain, otherwise assume it's in different domains.

```js
try {
  if ( window.parent[0].top.document )
    // Chrome & Firefox (same domain)
    var origins = location.ancestorOrigins||{};

} catch(err) {
  // Firefox (different domains CORS policy)
  var origins = {"0":"*","length":1};
};
console.log(origins);
if ( !origins.length || origins[ origins.length -1 ] == location.origin ) {
  // same domain

} else {
  // different domains
  var message = "Hellow Word!!";
   window.parent.postMessage( message, origins[ origins.length -1 ] );
};
```

Comment: this worked, with this i getting am full url rather than just the domain