# How to allow multiple origin domains by Access-Control-Allow-Origin in web.config file?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, cors, request-headers

Is there anyway to allow multiple cross-domains using Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the web.config file?

Currently I am using `*` to allow multiple domains at once.

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
```

But I don't want to use `*` because it's open for all domains and I only want to allow some specific domains.

So,there anyway to allow multiple cross-domains using the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in web.config file?

I found some related posts:

- [Access-control-allow-origin with multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323350/iis-access-control-allow-origin-with-multiple-domains)
- [Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains/4110601#4110601)

I already tried to get the request header to validate the request origin **(As suggested in post 1)** but was unsuccessful. Because I am using an iframe element, when I try to get the request header, it provides the origin (domain) of the iframe. But here I want the original (parent window) origin (domain).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference Microsoft provides an IIS module after several years.

Answer (score 1):

For IIS 7.5+ you can use IIS CORS Module: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module

Your web.config should be something like this replacing [origin_#] for your domains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
            <add origin="[origin_1]">
                <allowMethods>                    
                    <add method="GET" />
                    <add method="HEAD" />
                    <add method="POST" />
                    <add method="PUT" /> 
                    <add method="DELETE" /> 
                </allowMethods>
            </add>
            <add origin="[origin_2]">
                <allowMethods>
                    <add method="GET" />
                    <add method="HEAD" />
                    <add method="POST" />
                    <add method="PUT" /> 
                    <add method="DELETE" /> 
                </allowMethods>
            </add>
        </cors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You can find the configuration reference in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference

Answer (score 0):

I think the first method should work , but lets have a closer look on the `iframe` issue

is it possible to get the iframe parent document ? yes it is possible.

if you check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523158/how-to-get-the-parent-window-url-from-iframe) , you will find that [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer) should work inside your iframe.

hence the first solution should be valid.